# How can create individual wallet for each user

Tags: wallet, client, exchanges, account-to-account

I am going to develop an exchange website in PHP something like http://coinbase.com, 
Now, I have setup the http://bitcoindevkit.com/ for it and its running fine generating new addresses in the same wallet,
but now I need to create a individual wallet for each user, so how can create individual wallet for each user and then I can able to create address on that wallet.

Comment: Unfortunately not answer for a PHP based product, but there is a Django + Python library out there for creating through-the-web manageable wallets: https://github.com/kangasbros/django-bitcoin You could look here for inspiration.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Can this Django + Python library is able to create individual wallet for each user? and if it creates then can transfer is easily and speedly of Bitcoins from one wallet bitcoin address to another wallet bitcoin address?

Comment: Django is a web framework http://djangoproject.com/ Django-bitcoin library uses Django's user management and can automatically associate a wallet with a user profle.

Comment: Thanks! is this library also used by MtGox, Blockchain and Coinbase? Actually I am going to develop a exchange like coinbase, so this library will be best suitable for me?

Comment: Some library users are mentioned on the README which I linked before. I am pretty sure big players have their own internal codebase and not a library.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the bitcoind Account feature to track the different user 'wallets', this way a single 'wallet' or account can have as many address's as required which can all be be accounted for to that named account.  However I would also suggest not having this on your actual server, use a database to mirror what the bitcoin client shows, and hand actual withdrawals manually, (at least the larger ones) you may want to have a bitcoin daemon linked directly with a small amount of float to handle incidental day to day transactions.